# Numpy: Create new array from 1d integer array where each element in integer array represents the number of elements in the new array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This seems like it should be straightforward, but I'm stumped (also fairly new to numpy.)

I have a 1d array of integers *a*.

I want to generate a new 1d array *b* such that:

- the number of elements in *b* equals the sum of the elements in *a*
- The values in *b* are equal to some arbitrary constant divided by the corresponding element in *a*.

That's a mouthful, so here's an example of what I want to make it more concrete:

```
a = array([2,3,3,4])
CONSTANT = 120
.
.
.
b = array([60,60,
           40,40,40,
           40,40,40,
           30,30,30,30])
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: so the number a[i] is the time you repeat and also the divisor? a = [1,2,3] -> b = [c/1, c/2,c/2 , c/3,c/3,c/3,] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a pretty clear way to do this is

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2,3,3,4]) 
constant = 120

#numpy.repeat(x,t) repeats the val x t times you can use x and t as vectors of same len
b = np.repeat(constant/a , a)
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than mine. Nice one!

Comment: sorry I edited it so make it more clear and straightforward

Comment: Thank you both! Learned 2 new useful functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `np.concatenate` and good old fashioned `zip`:

```
>>> elements = CONSTANT / a
>>> np.concatenate([np.array([e]*n) for e, n in zip(elements, a)])
array([60., 60., 40., 40., 40., 40., 40., 40., 30., 30., 30., 30.])
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!

Comment: @AlexParthemer I think you should prefer the other answer. That uses more idiomatic numpy which will probably be better optimized.